# Discrete random variable with probability generating function problem. Help!

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable with probability generating
function:

$G_X(\theta)$ = $2(3-\theta)^{-1}$

1) If $Y$ = $X^{2}$ write down $P(Y=k)$ for $0\leq k \leq 10$, and find $E(Y)$

Firstly i know i have to get $G_X'(\theta)$ but i don't know how to do the rest. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: If you *really* want to, differentiate. However, I would rewrite our function as $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{\theta}{3}}$ and use $\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $G_X(\theta)$ is a generating function, so expand it and look at the coefficients of powers of $\theta$ to find the probabilities of $X$ taking small values, and so of $Y$ taking the squares of these values
- $G'_X( 1^- ) = E[X]$ and $G''_X( 1^- ) = E[X(X-1)]$

Comment: I have expanded the $G_X(\theta)$ and sum up the $G_X(\theta)$ but what should i do next?

Comment: If you have expanded $G_X(\theta)$ up to the $\theta^3$ term then $P(Y=k)$ should be easy

Answer (score 0):

The pgf gives you the probabilities $p_0,p_1,\ldots$ of values $0,1,\ldots$ in the form:

$$pgf(x)=p_0+p_1\cdot x+p_2\cdot x^2+\ldots$$

It is useful, first of all, because it allows you to express an infinite list of probabilities as one (finite) closed-form expression.

Note, that $pgf(0)=p_0$. To obtain the probability $p_k$, $k\ge 1$ you need to differentiate the function $k$ times, which gives you:

$$pgf^{(k)}(x)=p_k\cdot k!+p_{k+1}\cdot \frac{(k+1)!}{1!}x+\ldots,$$

take its value at 0, and divide by $k!$: $$pgf^{(k)}(0)=p_k\cdot k!$$.

Alternatively, if you can rewrite $pgf(x)$ as series, then the coefficients will give you the probabilities immediately.

---

In your question you are asked about the probabilities for $Y=X^2$, for values $\le 10$. First, if $X$ takes values $0,1,2,\ldots$, then $Y$ takes possible values $0,1,4,\ldots$, and there are only four of them $\le 10$. Moreover, $\mathbb{P}(Y=k^2)=\mathbb{P}(X=k)=p_k$. Now you have everything to find those 4 values.

To find $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ you need to calculate:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p_k\cdot k^2,$$

do it either directly, or consider the following well-known "work-around" using pgf:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathbb{E}(X(X-1))+\mathbb{E}(X)=pgf''(1)+pgf'(1).$$